# Why are 3-letter abbreviations for US timezones inconsistent with respect to daylight savings?

Tags: java, timezone

I came upon the following curiosity:-

- `TimeZone.getTimeZone` considers `PST` (["Pacific Standard Time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PST)) as equivalent to `America/Los_Angeles`, which observes daylight savings;
- but it considers `MST` (["Mountain Standard Time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MST)) as equivalent to `UTC-7`, which does not observe daylight savings.

This can be demonstrated with the following snippet:

```
System.out.println(
    TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST").hasSameRules(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-7")));
System.out.println(
    TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST").hasSameRules(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")));
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/lbiAPU)

And we can demonstrate that the timezones obtained using the three-letter abbreviations for the four main US timezones are inconsistent in their use of daylight savings:

```
for (String id : Arrays.asList("EST", "CST", "MST", "PST")) {
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
  System.out.printf("%s is %s; observes DST: %s%n",
      id, tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.LONG), tz.useDaylightTime());
}
```

Output:

```
EST is Eastern Standard Time; observes DST: false
CST is Central Standard Time; observes DST: true
MST is Mountain Standard Time; observes DST: false
PST is Pacific Standard Time; observes DST: true
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/dkvzS3)

Aside from the fact that three-letter abbreviations are best avoided anyway (the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) says "However, their use is deprecated..."), this seems very confusing, and a good source of subtle bugs, where you are or aren't expecting daylight savings to be used in multiple time zones.

Is there a reason for this difference in behaviour? Is there subtle property of US timezones which means this behaviour would be expected?

Comment: I guess, a question for [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First to say: We have to understand the **difference between time zone identifiers and time zone names**. Usually "MST" or "PST stand for (abbreviated) zone names and should be interpreted both as NOT in daylight saving state (suffix ST=Standard-Time).

However, old Java versions have (mis-)used those names also as identifiers, that is, allows to use these strings as parameters to factory methods like `TimeZone.getTimeZone(...)`. This leads us to the question: **What is a valid identifier?**

The underlying source of the zone data (rules, not names) originates from TZDB which is now maintained by IANA and its actual administrator Paul Eggert. It contains a file named [northamerica](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eggert/tz/master/northamerica). Following entry in this file tells us that MST is an identifier but not PST (instead "PST8PDT").

```
Zone    EST      -5:00  -   EST
Zone    MST      -7:00  -   MST
Zone    HST     -10:00  -   HST
Zone    EST5EDT      -5:00  US  E%sT
Zone    CST6CDT      -6:00  US  C%sT
Zone    MST7MDT      -7:00  US  M%sT
Zone    PST8PDT      -8:00  US  P%sT
```

However, Java still uses "PST" as identifier, too - via hardwired old-mappings:

```
private static String[][] oldMappings =
    {
        { "ACT", "Australia/Darwin" },
        { "AET", "Australia/Sydney" },
        { "AGT", "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires" },
        { "ART", "Africa/Cairo" },
        { "AST", "America/Anchorage" },
        { "BET", "America/Sao_Paulo" },
        { "BST", "Asia/Dhaka" },
        { "CAT", "Africa/Harare" },
        { "CNT", "America/St_Johns" },
        { "CST", "America/Chicago" },
        { "CTT", "Asia/Shanghai" },
        { "EAT", "Africa/Addis_Ababa" },
        { "ECT", "Europe/Paris" },
        { "IET", "America/Indiana/Indianapolis" },
        { "IST", "Asia/Kolkata" },
        { "JST", "Asia/Tokyo" },
        { "MIT", "Pacific/Apia" },
        { "NET", "Asia/Yerevan" },
        { "NST", "Pacific/Auckland" },
        { "PLT", "Asia/Karachi" },
        { "PNT", "America/Phoenix" },
        { "PRT", "America/Puerto_Rico" },
        { "PST", "America/Los_Angeles" },
        { "SST", "Pacific/Guadalcanal" },
        { "VST", "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh" }
    };
```

Just inspect the JDK-file [`sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfoFile.java/#219). So "PST" is mapped to America/Los_Angeles. "PST8PDT" is overtaken from TZDB and mapped to a fixed offset. What about "MST"? Here you can set a property how to interprete it, namely the boolean system property "sun.timezone.ids.oldmapping". Its default value is "false". The same mentioned file `ZoneInfoFile` also contains following switch depending on the value of the system property:

```
private static void addOldMapping() {
      for (String[] arrayOfString1 : oldMappings) {
        aliases.put(arrayOfString1[0], arrayOfString1[1]);
      }
      if (USE_OLDMAPPING) {
        aliases.put("EST", "America/New_York");
        aliases.put("MST", "America/Denver");
        aliases.put("HST", "Pacific/Honolulu");
      } else {
        zones.put("EST", new ZoneInfo("EST", -18000000));
        zones.put("MST", new ZoneInfo("MST", -25200000));
        zones.put("HST", new ZoneInfo("HST", -36000000));
      }
}
```

IBM has also written [an article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21250503) about this subject. All these oddities are just for backwards compatibility and should be avoided by users.

Comment: Thanks @Meno, that's a really thorough answer.